# Subdomain and @ record

Tags: dns

I'm facing an interrogation on how to set up an @ record for a sub DNS zone.

Imagine I have a domain example.com on my primary DNS servers.

I want to delegate the sub-zone france.example.com to a secondary external DNS server, so I create an NS record for this zone pointing to the correct server. This works.

I then want to declare the A record france.example.com on this secondary server.

It seems to me that this is not possible.

Can you confirm the correct workflow while trying to resolve this record?

1. The client asks its recursive DNS server for resolution.
2. The recursive DNS server determines who is the NS for example.com from the internet root servers.
3. The recursive DNS server asks the example.com name servers for the "france" record.

No issues for records xxx.france.example.com, they can be defined on the secondary server as the workflow changes this way :

1. The client asks its recursive DNS server for resolution.
2. The recursive DNS server determines who is the NS for example.com from the internet root servers.
3. The recursive DNS server determines who is the NS for france.example.com from the example.com servers.
4. The recursive DNS server asks the france.example.com name servers for the "xxx" record.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your second flow is correct, and it works in exactly the same way when resolving hostname `france.example.com`

Comment: Does it mean that the recursive DNS Server always asks for an NS record before requesting an A or a CNAME?

Comment: It will not ask for NS, but in case the asked server is not authoritative for the zone, it will respond with NS

Comment: Try http://dns.squish.net, it will give you a lot of insight

Comment: Perfect answer! thank you very much!

Comment: "who is the NS for example.com from the internet root servers." It goes iteratively, so through the TLD nameservers first (after the root ones).